# Need a more efficient join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

It's been a long time since I last did something with database so my knowledge has beenyet rusted. I have 2 SQL tables:

```
data(id, attr);
dependency(child, parent);
 #**child** and **parent** are the id from table **data**
```

I need to query all the **attr** corresponding to the entries in table **dependency**. Following is my attempt:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT data.attr FROM data WHERE data.id = child) AS child_attr,
(SELECT data.attr FROM data WHERE data.id = parent) AS parent_attr 
from dependency;
```

It works but very slow. I'm sure there's a better way to do it with join query but cannot come up with it yet. 
 Can someone please help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the `dependency` table to the `data` table twice to get the information you need:

```
SELECT d1.attr AS ChildAttr, d2.attr AS ParentAttr
FROM dependency AS dep
INNER JOIN data AS d1 ON dep.child = d1.id
INNER JOIN data AS d2 ON dep.parent = d2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT t2.attr, t3.attr
FROM dependency as t1
    INNER JOIN data as t2 on t1.child = t2.id
    INNER JOIN data as t3 on t1.parent = t3.id
```

Comment: +1 I think your solution is essentially the same as Linger. But thanks a lot.

Comment: yes - Linger had apparently posted his while I was posting mine.